# Sony Smartwatch - Vibrate smartwatch on widget tap

Tags: android, widget, sony, sony-smartwatch

I'm trying to develop a little widget extension that sends a sms on tap. This works quite well but I would like to get a confirmation that the sms has been sent by vibrating the smartwatch. Can i start the vibrator from widget extension?

As I understand sending a intent to host app should be enough to start vibration.

In my class extending WidgetExtension onTouch:

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage("124124512", null, "blaa", null, null); // Works fine

Intent intent = new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_VIBRATE_INTENT);
intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_ON_DURATION, 1000);
intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_OFF_DURATION, 1000);
intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_REPEATS, 1);
intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_AEA_PACKAGE_NAME, mContext.getPackageName());
intent.setPackage(mHostAppPackageName);
context.sendBroadcast(intent, Registration.HOSTAPP_PERMISSION); // No vibration
```

I have also tried creating separate Vibrator class extending ControlExtension:

```
public class Vibrator extends ControlExtension{

    public Vibrator(Context context, String hostAppPackageName) {
        super(context, hostAppPackageName);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void vibrate(){
        startVibrator(1000, 1000, 1);
    }

}
```

And firing vibrate from widget extension with no effect. Something i'm overlooking? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the only way to start a vibration on widget touch is to start a sparate ControlExtension:

Widget onTouch:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_START_REQUEST_INTENT);
intent.putExtra(Control.Intents.EXTRA_AEA_PACKAGE_NAME, mContext.getPackageName());
sendToHostApp(intent);
```

In RegistrationInformation:

Set getRquiredControlApiVersion to return 1.

and in ExtensionService add:

```
@Override
public ControlExtension createControlExtension(String hostAppPackageName) {
    return new Vibrator(hostAppPackageName, this);
}
```

and the Vibrator class:

```
public class Vibrator extends ControlExtension{


Vibrator(String hostAppPackageName, Context context){
    super(context, hostAppPackageName); 

}   

 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        vibrate();
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage("123456789", null, "BLAAA", null, null); 
        showBitmap(new SmartWatchSampleWidgetImage(mContext, 2).getBitmap());
    }

 @Override
    public void onTouch(final ControlTouchEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == Control.Intents.TOUCH_ACTION_PRESS) {

        }      
 }

public void vibrate(){

     if(hasVibrator()){
            startVibrator(1000, 500, 3);
     }
}
}
```

Does the job.